# отступы между фрагментами в linear layout

Tags: android

Есть `LinearLayout` в котором изначально ничего нет, но программно, с помощью `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.charactersListLayout, characterCard).commit()` в него добавляются неопределенное заранее количество фрагментов. Как между фрагментами сделать отступы?

Comment: а зачем вам использовать фрагменты? используйте обычный список на базе CardView и потом показывайте данные карточки в одном фрагменте, зачем велосипед изобретать?)

Comment: @Andrew я не могу найти, как создавать cardView с не самой примитивной разметкой из кода